# value not binding on choose from list with angular ngDefaultControl

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have list of option and using `ngDefaultControl` Angular directive but formcontrol value show empty on button click.
I want to bind value to form control on button click without using `setValue` or `patchValue` methods.

**example:**

```
 <h3>input text search dropdown</h3>
<div class="result">
  Selected Value:
  {{
    rootForm.get('category')?.value
      ? rootForm.get('category')?.value
      : 'Please select value'
  }}
</div>
<br />
<form [formGroup]="rootForm">
  <div class="list-popup">
    <ul class="list" [formControlName]="'category'" ngDefaultControl>
      <li class="item" *ngFor="let option of listValues" [value]="option">
        <button type="button" class="item-option" tabindex="-1">
          <span class="item-label">{{ option }}</span>
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

is it possible to bind value from UI in control for the same on selection? Could you please suggest me workaround.
here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formbuilder-tac35d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Angular **doesn't know what to do when you put a formControl** on a ul. In order to do what you want, you have to *create a component (or directive)* which implements [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) and move the code related to your form control there.

Implementing *ControlValueAccessor* means implementing the following three functions: *writeValue*, *registerOnChange*, *registerOnTouched*. In this way, Angular will know what to do with your component.

For example, you can follow this [example](https://www.tsmean.com/articles/angular/angular-control-value-accessor-example/)

Comment: thanks @Antonio. In my case I don't have input fields. it's ```<ul>``` with  ```<li>```  and ```<button>``` fields.  But  I am getting ```ERROR
Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute```.